# Android App - HTTPPost not acting as I want

Tags: php, android, android-intent, http-post, httpresponse

I'm currently developping an application for my website using the Android SDK and PHP server-side script.

I'm trying to send POST data like `username` and `password` through a `HttpClient` and a `HttpPost` request and get the results (`echo $result;`). Unfortunately, the `HttpResponse` is not working properly. The request is sended, the result is sended back by my PHP script but the `Intent` is not working yet.

There's my PHP code (I hided my DB info, you will understand why!):

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','','');
    mysql_select_db('', $con);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `` WHERE `username`='".$username."' AND `password`='".$password."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($users) == 1)
    {
        $usr = mysql_fetch_array($users);
        $usr['username'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

And there's my Java `login()` method:

```
public void login()
    {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.creationsmicroweb.com/app/login.php");

        String username = (String) findViewById(R.id.usr1).toString();
        String password = (String) findViewById(R.id.pwd1).toString();
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        try
        {
            // Disabling other request
            login.setEnabled(false);
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("http", "Executing HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String status = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Integer code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (!status.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("username", status);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                Toast.makeText(this, "You've been connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("login", "Logged in // " + response);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bad username/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Log.i("login", "Bad username/password // " + response);
                login.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("http", e.getMessage());
            login.setEnabled(true);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("http", e.getMessage());
            login.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private Object inputStreamToString(InputStream is)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try
        {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            { 
                total.append(line); 
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         // Return full string
        return total;
    }
```

The returned response by the PHP is not working properly with my Java code. In clear, when the user press "Login", the credentials are sent to the PHP, then the PHP return an answer (the username or error). After that, the Java code check if the answer is equals or not to "error" but this is not working. The login is made successfuly (I log everything) but the Intent method is not doing and no Toast message are displayed.

In clear, I'm trying to know why the request is not working properly. I'm starting in Java so I'm not the best!

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What's being returned from the PHP?

Comment: The PHP returns the username of the member if the credentials are good, else it returns `error` as simple string. Like HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I'm saying what is actually being returned when you query it? As in, what are you asking for help with?

Comment: The returned response by the PHP is not working properly with my Java code. In clear, when the user press "Login", the credentials are sent to the PHP, then the PHP return an answer (the username or `error`). After that, the Java code check if the answer is equals or not to `"error"` but this is not working. The login is made successfuly (I log everything) but the Intent method is not doing and no Toast message are displayed.

Comment: Do you have the activity you're trying to start in your manifest? If not you won't be able to start it

Comment: Yes, I added it to my manifest.

Comment: is this code inside of an activity? Also, do you see the log from this line `Log.i("login", "Logged in // " + response);` in your logcat when you run the method or no?

Comment: Indeed, it is in an activity, and Yes I see the line in the log. It is very weird!

Comment: Can you post the logcat please? I think there should be some info in there as to why the HomeActivity doesn't start and the Toast isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seeing any `Toasts`? If not then I think you might have the wrong `context` for them
also this line:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Bad username/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

you are missing off the `.show()`.

If this is in a View then use `getContext()` or `getBaseContext()` instead of `this`.

I recommend you use `Log.d()` to log the response and check if its what you expect.